# How to simplify this pasting calculator

Tags: vim

I have implemented a command in vim which pastes the result of a calculation into your file, i.e. you type

```
:CalP 34 * 89
```

and it should paste the result after your cursor.

The code is as follows:

```
command! -nargs=+ CalP :call Calculator(<q-args>) | normal! p
py from math import *

fun Calculator(arg)
  redir @"
  execute "py print " a:arg
  redir END
  let @" = strpart(@", 1)
endfun
```

This works but is messier than I would like for a simple operation, mainly because:

1. I don't know a better way to redirect the output of `py print ...` to the `"` register
2. I have to write `execute "py print " a:arg` because just `py print a:arg` doesn't work
3. The `let @" = strpart(@", 1)` removes the stray newline at the front of the register which `py print` creates, ideally this should be removed

I think this should be do-able in one line but I don't know enough vimscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll second @Amadan's suggestion. If you prefer Python over Vimscript, you can use the `pyeval()` function, e.g. directly from insert mode:

```
<C-R>=pyeval('34 * 89')<CR>
```

If you would like to keep your custom command, that's possible, too:

```
command! -nargs=+ CalP execute 'normal! a' . pyeval(<q-args>) . "\<Esc>"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know about that. That solves most of the problem, the only thing is that I wanted it to work with complex numbers as well and with pyeval I get the error `Failed to convert returned python object to vim value`, whereas in my function, if I import cmath in my vimrc, I can evaluate things like `exp(pi*1j)`

Comment: Wrap the expression in `str(...)` to make sure *Python* converts it to string instead of expecting Vim to do it.

Answer (score 4):

No scripting is needed for this. In insert mode, you can use `<Ctrl-R>=34*89<CR>` to insert the result of that calculation.

```
:help i_CTRL-R
:help expression
```